# mysql string not like column

Tags: mysql

What is the proper way of doing the following in a mysql query?:

```
$string="apple banana orange";
```

mysql column `A = "banana"`

mysql query: column `A` not included in `$string`

Thanks!

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: Thanks all! Let me try to clarify. I have a string $string="apple banana orange"; How can I do a mysql query where: a) column A IS included in $string b) column A IS NOT included in $string. Ex mysql_query("select * from DB where [A IS NOT included in $string]");

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If each row has a column called `A` that has space separated tokens you can run this:

```
SELECT * FROM table_name
WHERE LOCATE(CONCAT(' ',A,' '),'apple banana orange') = 0;
```

The reason I padded a blank on both sides would be to cover a situation like this:

```
SELECT * FROM table_name
WHERE LOCATE(CONCAT(' ',A,' '),'pineapple banana orange') = 0;
```

As a character string

- `apple` is in `apple banana orange`
- `apple` is in `pineapple banana orange`

In terms of semantics

- `apple` is in `apple banana orange`
- `apple` is not in `pineapple banana orange`

What if you were looking for `grape` ?

As a character string

- `grape` is in `apple banana orange grape`
- `grape` is in `apple banana orange grapefruit`

In terms of semantics

- `grape` is in `apple banana orange grape`
- `grape` is not in `apple banana orange grapefruit`

Give it a Try !!!

## CAVEAT

The query itself would yield a full table scan.

You should look into doing FULLTEXT indexes.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM table_name 
WHERE A NOT IN ('apple', 'banana', 'orange');
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this? (I have not tested it though but I think it would work)

```
<?php
$string = "apple banana orange";

//Make an array of each fruit in string (with delimiter space)
$items = explode(" " , $string);

//None of the fruits in $string would be listed in resultset
$query = "SELECT * FROM fruits WHERE columnA NOT IN ($items)";
//db-handling...
?>
```

UPDATE:
Don't make an array... ..do this instead...!
$items = str_replace(" ", ",", $string);

Comment: A PHP array cannot be placed into a query's `IN ()` clause.

Comment: Of course! You're right! $items could be using str_replace() - replacing spaces with comma in $string.